# Unable to use modal window for confirmation at submitting the form

Tags: grails

I used modal window using bootstrap and form is submitted using modal window yes or no confirmation button,but when i used modal window code inside the form then it submitted at yes button but outside the form if i used modal window then it's not submitted at yes button clicked.

Code of GSP is

```
  <g:form url="[resource: holidaysInstance, action:'delete']" method="DELETE" onSubmit="return modalwindow(this)">
  <input type="submit" class="btn bg-danger button_delete deleteHoliday" value="Delete"/>
  </g:form>
  Js are:
  function modalwindow(modalCOnfirmation)
  {

      $('#myModal').modal();
       return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For modal window submission, inside your form you should remove `onSubmit` and should use `onClick` event on the button

```
<g:form url="[resource: holidaysInstance, action:'delete']" id="formId" method="DELETE">
     ......
     Form elements will come here
     ......
     <input type="button" class="btn bg-danger button_delete deleteHoliday" id="${holidaysInstance.id}" onClick="return modalwindow(${holidaysInstance.id},'formId')" value="Delete"/>
</g:form>
```

Make sure to pass your object id (holidaysInstance.id) and form id (formId) in the onClick method as shown above.

Then in JS you need to do the following-

```
function modalwindow(modalConfirmation,formid)
{
    $('#myModal').modal();
    $('#modalYesButton').click(function () {
       $('#'+formid).submit();
       return true;   
    });
    return false;
}
```

So it will submit your form using JS through your modal window.